# How to select previous/next ROW in TABLE where COLUMN-VALUE

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a SQL Database, tablename: videos, in which I store videos.
The relevent columns from this table are the: the id, the `category_id` and the `video_id`.

The id, is a unique id, every video regardless of which category has a different id, the same id is never possible regardless of the category.

The `category_id` is also unique, and is each assigned to a category, e.g. Funny is 1.

For the `video_id` it is possible to have multiple rows that have the same value for this column. For instance, if one video is hosted on YouTube and exactly the same video is hosted on Vimeo. Then we have mirrors. True, what you are thinking how? Well, the database only stores the embed-code to the video, which is recalled by the pages.

The client-side pages on which the video appears recalls their videos simply by their assigned id; let's say:
- Someone opens category funny. Then the client-side looks: from tablename videos where `category_id` is 1.
- So lets assume there was a video called Funny Fails, with two mirrors YouTube and Vimeo, so both rows have a different id, but the same `video_id`. Funny Fails mirror of YouTube has for some reason got id 1, and Vimeo got id 2 (sake of simplicity), of course both videos have `video_id` 1 and are inside `category_id` 1.

The client side .php simply looks for the id, e.g.: `/category_detail.php?id=1` or `/videopage.php?id=1`.

Now you most probably understand the database and how client-side retrieves the information from the databse.

What we want to do is simply add two options to the page on the client-side. These are previous video and next video.

Assume we are browsing ID 110, `video_id` 123 inside `category_id` 1 it has no mirrors.

If we press Previous Video it should look for: `video_id` 122 inside `category_id` 1 and the dynamic part, the id itself. This ID is also the part of the link which makes the page e.g. this is the same id that comes after `.php?id=XXX`.

I have been sturggling a while, I know the solution is much simpler, but somehow I can't get to it.

There should also be a Next Video option which obviously will look for `video_id` 124 inside the same `category_id`, regardless of having mirrors or not.

Comment: what have u tried so far ?

Comment: If you can show us your code, we can help you debug it.

Comment: @awtv too much description. Please stat your question correctly and briefly.

Answer (score 1):

Previous:

```
  SELECT * FROM videos WHERE category_id = 1 AND video_id < 123 
  ORDER BY video_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Next:

```
  SELECT * FROM videos WHERE category_id = 1 AND video_id > 123 
  ORDER BY video_id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

And as Bill rightly says, you could `UNION` them so you have to query only once.

Comment: You can also combine those in a UNION.  :)

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is going in the right direction. However, I really can't get it done. Can you PM me your Skype, I can give you a small buck to check the source files and do it :), if you are up for it!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not up for it, free time (and no responsibility) is more valuable to me a.t.m. There's sites like rentacoder though.